# In CSS, which fonts are selected by generic font-family on common browsers/OS?

Tags: css, browser, fonts, operating-system

In CSS, which fonts are selected by generic font-family on common browsers/OS ?

Googled as much as possible, couldn't find an answer. This [article](https://css-tricks.com/sans-serif/) mention Helvetica on Mac for `sans-serif`. This [page](http://www.cssfontstack.com/) provides font availability by OS.

So, which fonts are selected by generic `font-family` on common browsers/OS ?

- serif
- sans-serif
- cursive
- fantasy
- monospace

Comment: font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

Answer (score 0):

There are no hard rules for this. And it can change. Best not to rely on this at all. A generic font is just that, generic.

If you want specific font(s), don't use generic family names, always use a concise font stack.

Generics like fantasy and cursive make it even more difficult as fonts like Comic Sans are seen as a bit of both... only serif/sans/monospace can be determined from the internal TTF OS2-panose, etc. tables reliably.

As for the answer, this is something you can easily find yourself by just viewing a page with each generic on various OSes and browsers you are targeting and then viewing the calculated font-family in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

**Generic font families**

| Browser | serif | sans-serif | monospace | cursive | fantasy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Safari 15.6 (Mac) | Times | Helvetica | Menlo | Apple Chancery | Zapfino |
| Chrome 104 (Mac) | Times | Helvetica | Courier | Apple Chancery | Papyrus |
| Firefox 103 (Mac) | Times | Helvetica | Menlo | Apple Chancery | Papyrus |

To get these results, I just created a basic test page and used the Developer Tools Inspector in each browser to show the rendered font.

Feel free to update this answer with additional tables if you're on Windows or some flavour of Linux.